# I am getting an error that message is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) 
{ 
    var message = "%c" + txt;
    var style = `color: ${color}`; 
    style += `background:${background}`;
    style += `fontSize:${fontSize}`;
    console.log(style) 
} 


function celebrateStyler(reason)
 {
    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px"; 
    if (reason == "birthday")  {  
        console.log('%cHappy Birthday', fontStyle) 
    }
    else if (reason == 'champions') {
        console.log('%cCongrats on the title!', fontstyle)
    }
    else { 
        console.log(message, style)
    }
 }

 consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'congrats!');
 celebrateStyler('birthday') 


function styleAndCelebrate() 
{
     consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
     celebrateStyler(reason);
} 
styleAndCelebrate('#ef7c8e', '#fae8e0', '30px', 'You made it!', 'champions')
```

I am getting an error that message is not defined . Now I know that var is function scoped so it can't be used outside the function. but Assignment on Coursera insists that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't use a variable outside of the scope it's defined.
However, the first error I get when trying to run your code is that `color` is undefined in the `styleAndCelebrate` function.

You didn't define the arguments for `styleAndCelebrate` so neither of the parameters  were passed into the function in on your last line:

```
styleAndCelebrate('#ef7c8e', '#fae8e0', '30px', 'You made it!', 'champions')
```

To fix this, define the required parameters for `styleAndCelebrate`:
`function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason)`

You're going to have the same problem with `celebrateStyler`

Comment: also, in the first function, you are re-assigning style 2 times. The only thing you are going to see logged to the console is the font size. Also, it seems as though you are still learning javascript as a beginner, so throw away var and start using let and const for variables. They are much better.